# Whatsapp chats only partially restored in new phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I had a Wiko Rainbow Jam which broke, I replaced it with an Echo Stellar, when I installed my SDcard in my new phone about 10 days ago my Whatsapp messages were only recovered until 25 July this year, so there's a gap of nearly 2 months, can I retrieve these somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your old phone is wrecked, I'm afraid you can't.

You were able to recover the data that was backed up.

It happened to me when I changed my phone - In my case, my old phone was still working, so all I had to do was turn it on, connect to internet and backup everything I wanted.

On Whatsapp, you go to `Config`->`Conversations` (or `messages`, not sure in English, since my app is in another language)->`Backup`. There you can check when it was your latest backup, and you can to force a backup.